Cannot able to get reponse while using particular class
cannot able to get response while using particular class
        [Function("SearchFailedEntries")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SearchFailedEntries([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "entries/search")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            try
            {
                string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
                var requestData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchEntries>(requestBody);
                if (requestData.IdList.Count < 1)
                {
                    return new BadRequestObjectResult(new { message = "Invalid ids" });
                }
                return await _ApiService.GetMissingDocumentsByIds(requestData.IdList); 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }

above function cannot return response while using class CmsEntryToDbSchema in SearchEntriesResponse class
    public class SearchEntriesResponse
    {
        public List<CmsEntryToDbSchema> FoundEntries { get; set; }

        public List<string> NotFoundEntries { get; set; }


    }

    public class CmsEntryToDbSchema
{
    public string id { get; set; }

    public CmsModel entry { get; set; }
    public int retriveCount { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}

expecting okObjectResult from the function while using CmsEntryToDbSchema
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetMissingDocumentsByIds(List<string> ids)
    {
        try
        {

            var missingIds = new List<string>();
            //var foundEntriesId = await _cmsEntriesCollection.SearchDocumentById(ids);

            var foundEntries = await _cmsEntriesCollection.GetMultipleEntriesById(ids);




            foreach (var id in ids) {
                if (foundEntries.Any(x => x.id != id))
                {
                    missingIds.Add(id);
                }
            }

            //var missingIds = ids.Except(foundEntries).ToList();

            return new OkObjectResult(new SearchEntriesResponse() { FoundEntries = foundEntries, NotFoundEntries = missingIds });
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }

Below Given was GetMultipleEntriesById
        public async Task<List<CmsEntryToDbSchema>> GetMultipleEntriesById(List<string> ids)
    {
        var filter = Builders<CmsEntryToDbSchema>.Filter.In("_id", ids);
        return await _collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
    }


Where is your CmsEntryToDbSchema Class? Please add it so we can verify why it's not working

Sure @Aaron , i have added

Now also please add the code where you try to return an OkObjectResult? I also need to understand what this function does GetMissingDocumentsByIds. You simply never return an OkObjectResult...

Let me add @Aaron

I created the response object manually with the following code:
[Function("SearchFailedEntries")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SearchFailedEntries([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "entries/search")] HttpRequestData req)
{
    try
    {
        return new OkObjectResult(new SearchEntriesResponse()
        {
            FoundEntries = new List<CmsEntryToDbSchema> { new CmsEntryToDbSchema { entry = new CmsModel
            {
                id = "SomeIdHere"
            }} },
            NotFoundEntries = new List<string> { "test", "test2" }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
}

If I send a post request I get the expected response

Since I can not verify what response you get from your api service I suggest that you debug and try to find if the List that is returned actually has data in the correct format. With my code please try to start from scratch and add line by line to see where your code breaks.
